# Why is there a lag in my game everytime my sound is being played in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

The sound plays everytime I tap the screen but there is a slight hiccup in the game where you could see it lag the screen. How would I fix this?

```
class level1: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

    var jumpSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tapsound", ofType: "wav")!)

    var jumpAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    jumpAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: jumpSound, error: nil)
    jumpAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()



    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    theHero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 200))
    jumpAudioPlayer.play()

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lower the quality/bitrate of the audio that you play.

Comment: I didn't create the sound I got it from this site freesounds.org. @Fuad

Comment: use a site like http://media.io/ to lower the quality, and this should stop the lag.

Comment: its a .wav file what do I convert it to?

Comment: you can convert a wav file to a (lower quality) wav file

Comment: then pick the lowest quality, to make sure that your problem is fixed. you can slowly try higher qualities if your problem is fixed